# ActionScript 3 - Reseting timer every frame (Quiz)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, countdowntimer

I have been attempting to create a simple quiz in which you chose an answer, play right / wrong animation, then let you choose another question. Each question frame gives you 30 seconds to choose an answer and then forwards you to the "time is up" frame. Pretty simple. So far, everything has been working smooth except the timer. I can get it to work within a single frame, but when u click a button or for some other reason get re-directed to another frame, it crashes the whole program.

I theorized I can fix that by stoping the timer at "exit frame event", however that only prevented the timer from even starting (while the rest of the program continued to work smoothly);

Posting the code may and WILL not be enough so check the file out for yourself:
http://www.filedropper.com/semifinalsq

I need this for a school quiz and I haven't been able to find anything on the internet for days. I may possibly have multiple errors or errors in the way I've 'graphically' constructed and linked the whole thing, in which case I cannot fix it without somebody taking a look at the whole program.

If you can make anything from the code of only 1 frame:

```
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownHandler);
function  countdownHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{  
countdown.text = 30-myTimer.currentCount+" s";
if(myTimer.currentCount==30){gotoAndStop(5)}    
}
```

This is my timer code, where frame 5 is the "time is up" frame. This bit works perfectly, but how do I build upon it so it resets whenever a new frame with a timer is entered? (So, how do I stop it and restart it in certain frames?);

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please post the relevant code. (Some people don't like downloading files from strangers).

Comment: Where do you start (and stop) your timer?

Comment: Before going to frame 5,  you'll want to stop your timer, and remove the event listener(s) on it.

Comment: I have not defined any triger events. It simply begins whenever the frame with the question begins. (I want it to reset on every frame with a question, but I also have frames which don't need a timer and thus no dynamic text object for the timer to display in, so whenever the frame with this code enters those frames, flash freaks out)

Comment: Yes I have attempted that but whenever I did that, the timer wouldn't work at all...

Comment: the only thing I can say is that the whole structure is incorrect. generally writing as3 codes on frames is totally incorrect and you need to change it.

Comment: I should note that I have verry bare-bone understanding of flash. I have the timer code on a seperate layer, while (just because I have to) I keep the code for the buttons on the layer with the button objects. So I really need step-by-step help on this matter.

Comment: Should I put the following code within an EXIT_FRAME event-triggered function?                                     myTimer.stop();
myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);

Comment: Well I did and it didn't work. The timer would not begin at all, while the rest works fine.

Comment: you don't want to use ENTER or EXIT frame handler, those run every tick of the frame rate regardless if the playhead is moving (So even if you're stopped on a frame,  if your frame rate is set to 30fps those events will keep firing 30 times every second).

Comment: Oh well, that explains alot. I figured they only run whenever you open up a frame. Anyway I fixed it by putting in the stopTimer within the buttonHandler functions. Works smoothly!

Comment: what you want to do, is when a question is done (whether it's been answered or the timer completed), you'll want to stop the timer, remove it's listener, then move on (to frame 5 or wherever), then when you start a new question,  start the timer again and add the listener back

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
myTimer.stop();
myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownHandler);
```

Added within the function called by the buttons. Since it is a quiz, the answers are buttons and lead to another frame, while previously stopping the timer and removing it's listener (code above goes before 'goto' frame and stop ... );

Although this may not help in other situations, for a quiz of similar structure it is a pretty simple solution.

*Special thanks to user LDMS*